# How to get frames from a socket function and store them in a list?

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I have a small web application in flask, which consists of passing a streaming video from the client side with the webcam to the server with javascript, I have already done this, but I want to store these frames in a list, and I don't know how to store them, someone who could help me by favor.

my code is:

```
@socketio.on('image')
def image(data_image):
     pimg = imread(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data_image)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be a solution;

```
pimg = base64.b64encode(pimg)
pimg = pimg.decode()
pimg = ["data:image/pimg;base64,"+ pimg]
```